# Need Distinct address, ID etc with the different amount in one table using Plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, google-bigquery

Need help on the below scenario, please.
I want distinct address, ID, etc with the different amount in one table using plsql or

For example below is the current table

```
Address            aRea zipcode ID      Amount  amount2 qua number
123 Howe's drive    AL  1234    1234567  100     20      1  666666
123 Howe's drive    AL  1234    1234567   5      05      2  abcccc
123 east drive      AZ  456     8910112  200     11      1  777777
123 east drive      AZ  456     8910112   5       5      2   SDN133
116 WOOD Ave        NL  1234    2325890  3.23   1.25     1  10483210
116 WOOD Ave        NL  1234    2325890  3.24   1.26     2  10483211
```

[image]

I need the output as below.

```
Address            aRea zipcode ID      Amount  amount2 qua number
123 Howe's drive    AL  1234    1234567  100     20      1  666666
                                          5      05      2  abcccc
123 east drive      AZ  456     8910112  200     11      1  777777
                                          5       5      2   SDN133
116 WOOD Ave        NL  1234    2325890  3.23   1.25     1  10483210
                                         3.24   1.26     2  10483211
```

[image]

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle, while you tagged your question Big Query. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language, but the question seems to be asking for a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I would recommended below approach

```
#standardSQL
SELECT address, area, zipcode, id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(amount, amount2, qua, number)) info
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY address, area, zipcode, id
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This type of task is usually better done on application side.

You *can* do this with SQL - but you need a column to order the record consistently:

```
select
    case when rn = 1 then address  end as address,
    case when rn = 1 then area     end as area,
    case when rn = 1 then zipcode end as zipcode,
    case when rn = 1 then id       end as id,
    amount,
    amount2,
    qua,
    number
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by address, area, zipcode, id 
            order by ??
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
order by address, area, zipcode, id, ??
```

The `partition by` clause of the window function lists the columns that you want to "group" together; you can modify it as you really need.

The `order by` clause of `row_number()` indicates how rows should be sorted within the partition: you need to decide which column (or set of columns) you want to use. For the output tu make sense, you also need an `order by` clause in the query, where the partition and ordering columns will be repeated.